# How to define letter-spacing of a custom environment?

Tags: typography, kerning, preamble, letterspacing

Say I have:

```
%defines a vertical bridge hand with seat name
\newcommand{\hand}[5]{
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.0cm}
\begin{tabbing}
\textsc{#1} \= \\
\s\Hair\=#2 \\
\h \> #3 \\
\d \> #4 \\
\c \> #5
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage} }%
```

to produce:
[image]

How do I customize the letter-spacing (between letters/numbers *after* the suit symbol) *inside a custom* environment? Is it also possible to add custom kerning between certain letters/numbers? (Say apart from my custom letter-spacing, I want to adjust the kerning between K and J.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,english]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%********************************************************************************
%Use MnSymbol suit symbols
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolCards}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.2] MnSymbolC12}{}

\newcommand{\mndiamond}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A2}}}
\newcommand{\mnheart}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A3}}}
\newcommand{\mnspade}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A4}}}
\newcommand{\mnclub}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A5}}}

\renewcommand{\c}{\mnclub}
\renewcommand{\d}{\mndiamond}
\newcommand{\h}{\mnheart}
\newcommand{\s}{\mnspade}
%********************************************************************************


%Defines "hair space" to be used after suit symbols
\newcommand{\Hair}{\ifmmode\mskip1mu\else\kern0.08em\fi}

%defines a vertical bridge hand with seat name
\newcommand{\hand}[5]{
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.0cm}
\begin{tabbing}
\textsc{#1} \= \\
\s\Hair\=#2 \\
\h \> #3 \\
\d \> #4 \\
\c \> #5
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage} }%


\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\noindent \hand{North}{KJ2}{AQ742}{K9}{K87}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest a change in syntax, which has the benefit of making reformatting much easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{xparse}

%***
%Use MnSymbol suit symbols
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolCards}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.2] MnSymbolC12}{}

\newcommand{\mndiamond}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A2}}}
\newcommand{\mnheart}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A3}}}
\newcommand{\mnspade}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A4}}}
\newcommand{\mnclub}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A5}}}

%***

% Defines the separation between cards
\newcommand{\cardsep}{\hspace*{0.3em}}

%defines a vertical bridge hand with seat name
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hand}{mm}
 {
  \blackened_hand:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_blackened_hand_seq
\clist_new:N \l_blackened_suit_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabbing}
  \textsc{#1} \\
  \mnspade   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } \\
  \mnheart   \>          \> \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } \\
  \mndiamond \>          \> \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } \\
  \mnclub    \>          \> \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 }
  \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_set_suit:n
 {
  \clist_set:Nx \l_blackened_suit_clist { \seq_item:Nn \l_blackened_hand_seq { #1 } }
  \clist_use:Nn \l_blackened_suit_clist { \cardsep }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hand{North}{K,J,2; A,Q,10,4,2; K,9; K,8,7}

\end{document}
```

The hand is split into its components at semicolons; then each component is split at commas, so we are able to insert whatever we want. Spaces in the second argument of `\hand` are completely irrelevant (except you shouldn't put a space in the middle of `10`, of course), so the input can be better laid out.

[image]

A variant that allows for “horizontal” setting of a hand, with just `\hand*`. I'd keep the seat name for maximum portability: this way you just have to copy and paste a hand, adding or removing `*`. Line breaks are possible after the commas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{xparse}

%********************************************************************************
%Use MnSymbol suit symbols
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolCards}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.2] MnSymbolC12}{}

\newcommand{\mndiamond}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A2}}}
\newcommand{\mnheart}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A3}}}
\newcommand{\mnspade}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A4}}}
\newcommand{\mnclub}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A5}}}

%********************************************************************************


%Defines "hair space" to be used after suit symbols
\newcommand{\cardsep}{\hspace*{0.3em}}

%defines a vertical bridge hand with seat name
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hand}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \blackened_hand_horizontal:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \blackened_hand:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_blackened_hand_seq
\clist_new:N \l_blackened_suit_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand_horizontal:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \mbox{\mnspade   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } },~
  \mbox{\mnheart   \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } },~
  \mbox{\mndiamond \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } },~
  \mbox{\mnclub    \ \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_hand:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_blackened_hand_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabbing}
  \textsc{#1} \\
  \mnspade   \= \cardsep \= \blackened_set_suit:n { 1 } \\
  \mnheart   \>          \> \blackened_set_suit:n { 2 } \\
  \mndiamond \>          \> \blackened_set_suit:n { 3 } \\
  \mnclub    \>          \> \blackened_set_suit:n { 4 }
  \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_set_suit:n
 {
  \clist_set:Nx \l_blackened_suit_clist { \seq_item:Nn \l_blackened_hand_seq { #1 } }
  \clist_use:Nn \l_blackened_suit_clist { \cardsep }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hand*{North}{K,J,2; A,Q,10,4,2; K,9; ---}

\bigskip

\hand{North}{K,J,2; A,Q,10,4,2; K,9; K,8,7}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change the definition of `\blackened_set_suit:n` by

```
\tl_const:Nn \c_blackened_ten_tl { 10 }
\tl_new:N \l_blackened_suit_tl
\seq_new:N \l_blackened_suit_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \blackened_set_suit:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_blackened_suit_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_blackened_hand_seq { #1 } }
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l_blackened_suit_tl
   { --- } % no card in the suit
   {
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_blackened_suit_tl { 10 } { \c_blackened_ten_tl }
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_blackened_suit_seq { } \l_blackened_suit_tl
    \seq_use:Nn \l_blackened_suit_seq { \cardsep }
   }
 }
```

then you have to remove the commas from the input above; spaces are again irrelevant, so from an input such as

```
\hand*{North}{KJ2; AQ1042; ; K 8 7 }

\bigskip

\hand{North}{KJ2; AQ1042; ; K 8 7}
```

you get

[image]

I'm not sure of any gain.

Comment: Your answers always leave me in awe. Notwithstanding other helpful people, your answers are always through, with extreme attention to detail, and complete. Thank you ever so much.

Comment: What would be the horizontal version of your macro (without seat name)?

Comment: @blackened I added a possible solution.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to elaborate. *If possible*, separated by {}, I guess I do not need line breaks. My initial rather simple macro was: `\def\cards#1 #2 #3 #4 {\s{} #1\quad\h{} #2\quad\d{} #3\quad\c{} #4 }` And I just want to be able to control the letter spacing. In your macro the cards were separated by commas, does that mean that they have to be separated one way or another? (Because of “10” problem?) Same question also about your initial macro. In general, the more flexibility the macro provides, the more I can tinker with it and perhaps tweak it slightly for other similar purposes.

Comment: @blackened As I said, defining a macro with argument delimited by spaces is something I don't recommend. It's too rigid and error prone. With commas and semicolons you gain much more flexibility and clarity of input, with no real hindrances.

Comment: (First, thank you.) Your advice noted. Do I understand correctly that it is not possible to make your macro work so that I will not need to separate the cards with commas. (That would be **a lot less** time consuming, e.g. `\hand{North}{KJ2; AQ1042; K9; K87}`?)

Comment: Okay. If you say so.

Comment: It is certainly possible. You have the macros, now.

Comment: I owe you. One thing: I understand not one thing from your macro. Where do I find relevant information to get acquainted with it?

Comment: One more thing: The seat label in the horizontal version is not printed—does it serve any purpose there? `\hand*{KJ2; AQ1042; ; K 8 7 } instead of \hand*{North}{KJ2; AQ1042; ; K 8 7 }`

Comment: @blackened I think that if you use it in one version it should be there also in the second one: you can copy-paste more easily, can't you? Or maybe you'll want to print an abbreviated form, or whatever.

Comment: (Please forgive me for bugging you for what you may consider unnecessary details.) In your vertical hand macro, in some cases I need the vertical hand without the seat name, just the hand. Is it possible to modify your macro so that when there is no seat name, it does not occupy vertical an empty vertical space. Or does that require a third version of the macro?

Comment: @blackened Just change the line with ``\textsc{#1} \\`` into ``\tl_if_blank:nF { #1 } { \textsc{#1} \\ }`` and use an empty first argument to `\hand`, such as `\hand{}{K,J,2; A,Q,10,4,2; K,9; ---}`

Comment: Dear egreg: I need a special version of your macro. I cannot ask it in the comment (because I need to show an example image), I cannot ask it as a question, it will be flagged as too specific, and only you will be able to answer it. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: @blackened No question can be flagged as too specific; there's “too broad”, but it's a slightly different thing. `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your `\newcommand{\hand}...` you can use:

```
\def\hand#1#2#3#4#5{\vtop{
   \hbox{\textsc{#1}}
   \handA \s{#2}
   \handA \h{#3}
   \handA \d{#4}
   \handA \c{#5}
}}
\def\handA#1#2{\hbox{\hbox to1em{\hss#1\hss}\handB#2\relax}}
\def\handB#1{\ifx#1\relax\else #1\if1#1\else\kern2pt \fi\expandafter\handB\fi}
```

The kerning between letters are set to 2pt, see the `\handB` definition. You can change this.

Edit: I added one exception: after 1 is not `\kern`, so ten is set correctly (and a single 1 is no card).

**Edit2** If you need the syntax suggested by egreg, i. e.:

```
\hand{North}{K,J,2; A,Q,10,4,2; K,9; K,8,7}
```

then my macros can be modified by this way:

```
\def\hand#1#2{\handX{#1}#2;}
\def\handX#1#2;#3;#4;#5;{\vtop{
   \hbox{\textsc{#1}}
   \handA \s{#2}
   \handA \h{#3}
   \handA \d{#4}
   \handA \c{#5}
}}
\def\handA#1#2{\hbox{\hbox to1em{\hss#1\hss}\handB#2,,}}
\def\handB#1,{\ifx,#1,\else \ignorespaces#1\kern2pt \expandafter\handB\fi}
```

Note, that my macros needn't any additional packages, any `\ExplSynaxOn` etc. What leave me in awe: why the simplest and TeX primitive solutions are not preferred here.

Comment: +1. Very nice indeed. I'd probably go with a smaller kern amount that `2pt`, though.

Comment: Your macro, for instance, doesn't remove spaces *after* a card. I know it can be done, of course, but why bother when a higher level set of macros provides this *automatically*?

Comment: This is not a good example of an application where we explicitly need to remove `\kern2pt` after the list of cards. But if somebody needs it, he/she can add `\kern-2pt` after `\handB#2,,`. All is easy without special packages.

Comment: @wipet I hope my above comment did not annoy you in some way. Believe it or not, your answer also went into my notes, and taught things I was not aware of.

Comment: @wipet What would be the “horizontal” version of your first macro? (That the whole hand will be shown horizontally.)

Comment: @blackened I don't know exactly what you want. Maybe you can try to add `\noindent` before `\hbox{\textcs{#1}}` in the macro `\hand`.

Comment: @wipet Instead of vertically, the hand will be output horizontally, in one line: e.g. sAKQ  h10854  dAJ9  c432

Comment: @blackened `\noindent` as mentioned in my previous comment does this.

Comment: @wipet Yes, just tried and it worked. Though, I do not understand *why* it works! Thanks.